# Many boolean properties in react state - how to refactor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

I have a React component that is a report with many buttons. You can open some subreports on table row click or by button click. I keep in state boolean values for each report. Basically my State interface for types looks like this:

```
interface State {
  isSubreportVisible: boolean;
  isLogsVisible: boolean;
  isSelectStatusVisible: boolean;
  isMoneyVisible: boolean;
  isTargetStoreWarningVisible: boolean;
  isMultiVisible: boolean;
  isCancelVisible: boolean;
  isPrintVisible: boolean;
}
```

Then my initial state is like this:

```
public state: State = {
  isSubreportVisible: false,
  isLogsVisible: false,
  isSelectStatusVisible: false,
  isMoneyVisible: false,
  isMultiVisible: false,
  isTargetStoreWarningVisible: false,
  isCancelVisible: false,
  isPrintVisible: false,
};
```

And inside component I have:

```
{isSubreportVisible && (
  <Subreport
    ...
    ...
    ...
  />
)}
```

File of the component is really long - almost 600 lines of code. Is there anything could be done here? All subreports in modals are connected to this component?
Is it a good pattern to create a file called for example "types.tsx" and move all interfaces there (State, StateToProps, Props etc.)? Any ideas? Maybe it could be better to have just one string value in state - `currentModalVisible` and to keep there its names from enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe it could be better to have just one string value in state - currentModalVisible and to keep there its names from enum?

This depends -- is only one modal visible at a time?  If so then I would store a single value which is either `null`/`undefined` or the name of the visible modal.  If the modals toggle independently then you will want to store a `boolean` for each one.

Either way, I think a good goal here is to have generalized functions that take a `string` key for the modal as an argument.  You want to be able to call things like `isModalVisible('print')`, `toggleModalVisible('print')`, `setModalVisible('print', false)`, etc.

I would define a `type` for the props that are available to the modals/subreports.  You want to require that the components cannot require any additional props.  That way you can call a component by its variable and pass it all the available props some will be ignored).

For maximum flexibility, you could even pass the available modals as a prop.

```
interface ModalProps {
  someKey: string;
}

interface FlexibleSettings {
  // what to display in your tab/toggle
  // optional because can default to a cased version of the `key`
  buttonText?: React.ReactNode;
  // the component to render when selected
  modal: React.ComponentType<ModalProps>;
}

interface VeryFlexibleComponentProps<Keys extends string> {
  // pass the modals as an object keyed by the modal key
  modals: Record<Keys, FlexibleSettings>;
  // can start with one visible
  initialVisible?: Keys;
  // need to access the ModalProps somewhere
  // maybe some come from this component and can be omitted
  modalProps: ModalProps;
}

const VeryFlexibleComponent = <Keys extends string>({
  modals,
  initialVisible,
  modalProps
}: VeryFlexibleComponentProps<Keys>) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(initialVisible); // type Keys | undefined

  // need an uppercase variable to call a component with JSX
  const CurrentModal = visible ? modals[visible].modal : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Select Modal</h3>
      {(Object.keys(modals) as Keys[]).map((key) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="visible"
            value={key}
            id={key}
            checked={visible === key}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (e.target.checked) setVisible(key);
            }}
          />
          <label htmlFor={key}>
            {modals[key].buttonText ?? _startCase(key)}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
      {CurrentModal !== undefined && (
        <div>
          <h3>Viewing Modal</h3>
          <CurrentModal {...modalProps} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggling-visible-component-z3swi?file=/src/App.tsx)